# jQuery livestamp.js not working at second page

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, livestamp.js

I'm using [`livestamp.js`](https://mattbradley.github.io/livestampjs/) for `times ago` function.

The jQuery is from https://mattbradley.github.io/livestampjs/.

In the first page, it's render `5 years ago` correctly. I mentioned it like this.

```
<span data-livestamp="2010-10-10 10:10:10"></span>
```

In the second page, I mention it as below

```
<tr>
   <th>
       <span data-livestamp="2010-10-10 10:10:10"></span>
   </th>
<tr>
```

But it's not rendering anything, I tried everything. what am I doing wrong?

**Note:** I included the jquery for both the page.

Comment: and livestamp.js too?

Comment: @Gavriel sorry i didn't get you..

Comment: do you also have livestamp.js included on the 2nd page, or only jQuery?

Comment: i'm working with laravel directory. and i add the .js file into the assets, where js should be placed. Means, added only once

Comment: and is it added? do you see it on page2?

Comment: yes, it has the livestamp

Comment: and moment.js as well?

Comment: any javascript errors? Can we see the pages somewhere?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: IN jquery it showing the error at `size: Math.round(0.8 * (+placeholder.css("font-size").replace("px", "") || 13)),`

Comment: strange. maybe your css is incorrect?